# Como iterar variável no angular toda vez que uma certa condição for atendida?

Tags: angular, angular-6

```
     <div *ngFor="let elemento of team.elementos" class="{{elemento.colunas}}">
            <div *ngIf="(elemento.dataPublicacao < hoje) && (elemento.dataValidade > hoje)">
              <span>{{qtdIntegrantes}}</span>
              <div *ngIf="qtdIntegrantes == 1">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle" src="{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'img')}}" alt="">
                  <h4>{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'nome')}}</h4>
                  <p style="margin-bottom:0px" class="text-muted">{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'posto')}}</p>
                  <p style="margin-bottom:0px" class="text-muted numdesk">{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'telf')}}</p>
                  <a class="text-muted nummob"
                    href="{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'telfhref')}}">{{getCampoElem(elemento, 'telf')}}</a>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
     </div>
```

Basicamente toda vez que a condição do `ngIf` for atendida, a `qtdIntegrantes` deveria aumentar, existe alguma maneira de fazer isto no Angular?

Comment: Melhor fazer essa logica no typescript do que no ngIf

Comment: por que não fazer no ts?

Comment: Como chamaria a função no ts?

Comment: o ```ngIf``` apenas é um filtro para renderização baseado na condição inserida. Se você quer alterar o valor da variável ```qtdIntegrantes``` você pode fazer um for no ts que altere o valor da variável.